# Script SQL Dim Table Date on IBM DB2

Tags: sql-server, db2, business-intelligence

I'am a db2 user and it's my first time using this database i am used to use SQLserver database , so my probleme is that i have a script i always use on order to generate a table date in sql server but when i used the same code it didin't work on my db2 too much error lignes , this is my code :

```
       use dw_test_pfe 
       SET LANGUAGE 'FRENCH';

        WITH DateCTE
        AS (
        SELECT cast('20000915' AS DATETIME) Datevalue

     UNION ALL

   SELECT datevalue + 1
   FROM DateCTE
   WHERE datevalue + 1 < = '20201231'
    )
  SELECT CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), Datevalue, 112) AS INT) AS Temps_PK
,CAST(Datevalue AS DATE) AS [Date]
,cast(DATENAME(d, datevalue) AS NVARCHAR(10))+' - '+cast(DATENAME(Month, DateValue) AS NVARCHAR(30))+' - '+cast(DATENAME(year, DateValue) AS NVARCHAR(30)) AS [Jour_Moi_Annee]
,cast(DATENAME(year, DateValue) AS INT) AS [Year]
,cast(DATENAME(year, DateValue) + REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(Month(DateValue))) + CAST(Month(DateValue) AS VARCHAR) AS INT) AS ID_Month
,cast(MONTH(DateValue) AS INT) AS [Month]
,cast(DATENAME(Month, DateValue) AS NVARCHAR(30)) AS [Lib_Month]
,cast(DATENAME(d, datevalue) AS INT) AS [Day]
,DATEPART(DW, datevalue) AS [Id_Lib_Day]
,cast(DATENAME(DW, Datevalue) AS NVARCHAR(10)) AS [Lib_Day]
,cast(DATENAME(WEEK, Datevalue) AS INT) AS [Week]
,cast(DATENAME(dayofyear, Datevalue) AS INT) AS [DayOfYear]
,cast(DATENAME(DW, Datevalue) AS NVARCHAR(10))+' - '+cast(DATENAME(d, datevalue) AS NVARCHAR(10))+' - 
'+cast(DATENAME(Month, DateValue)AS NVARCHAR(30))  AS [Jour_mois_lettre]
 into DimTemps FROM DateCTE D

   ORDER BY Datevalue
   OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

this is my code it works well on sqlserver base but i can't use it on db2 server , all the code is red when i put this script if you guys can adjust my code or bring a new one , i need just to generate a dimension date thank you all

Answer (score 2):

Edit:Since you probably run the statements against DB2 9.7 (not supported since sept 2017) or even older you have first tou create the table then insert the data

```
set current locale lc_time 'fr-fr';
create table DimTemps as (
  with DateCTE(dateValue) as (
    values date('2000-09-15')
    union all
    select dateValue + 1 day from dateCte where dateValue < '2020-12-31'
  )
  select
    int(dec(datevalue, 8)) as Temps_PK,
    dateValue "Date",
    to_char(dateValue, 'dd - month - yyyy') as "Jour_Moi_Annee",
    year(datevalue) as "Year",
    year(datevalue) * 100 + month(datevalue) as "Month",
    to_char(datevalue, 'month') as  "Lib_Month",
    day(datevalue) as "Day",
    dayofweek(datevalue) as "Id_Lib_Day",
    to_char(datevalue, 'day') as "Lib_Day",
    week(datevalue) as "Week",
    dayofyear(datevalue) as "DayOfYear",
    to_char(dateValue, 'day - dd - month') as "Jour_mois_lettre"
  from datecte
);
```

then

```
insert into DimTemps 
      with DateCTE(dateValue) as (
        values date('2000-09-15')
        union all
        select dateValue + 1 day from dateCte where dateValue < '2020-12-31'
      )
      select
        int(dec(datevalue, 8)) as Temps_PK,
        dateValue "Date",
        to_char(dateValue, 'dd - month - yyyy') as "Jour_Moi_Annee",
        year(datevalue) as "Year",
        year(datevalue) * 100 + month(datevalue) as "Month",
        to_char(datevalue, 'month') as  "Lib_Month",
        day(datevalue) as "Day",
        dayofweek(datevalue) as "Id_Lib_Day",
        to_char(datevalue, 'day') as "Lib_Day",
        week(datevalue) as "Week",
        dayofyear(datevalue) as "DayOfYear",
        to_char(dateValue, 'day - dd - month') as "Jour_mois_lettre"
      from datecte
```

Comment: thank you for your response but the last sentence is red with data , the word with is red and there is an info like " no was attended afrer with "

Comment: please need help when i put no after with like it becomes with no data the script is running but there is no insert like querry is done in 1sec and i can't find my table at all

Comment: @aze Which DB2 are you using, platform and version ? try `select service_level from sysibmadm.env_inst_info` to know

Comment: service_level : DB2 v11.1.4041.600

Comment: so what should I do know ? i need to create the table first with the columns then insert with the second code you gave it ?

Comment: DB2 V11 should run the code I gave you first, I tested it against DB2 11, did you try to run the code despite `with data` apprearing red ? what software do you use as a SQL client ?

Comment: this is what shows me when i execute the first code even with the red error with data : set current locale lc_time 'fr-fr'  

 
Query execution time => 1 ms

Script: Script12.sql
Database Name: MOOV_STG
Authorization Id (Database): Administrateur

Comment: its it runs ok but no result i tried to use Select * from DimTemps ; NOTHING happens tells me Dimtemps is not defiened

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216619/discussion-between-nfgl-and-aze).